# Get data from this json string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string

`["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"]`

I need to get at the data only and I want to extract the string to get the following :

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg
```

I have tried to use JSON.parse but this does not seem to work

Any help woul dbe appreciated

Comment: Do you *really* have a JSON string, or just a normal array? Why does `JSON.parse` not work, what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1):

[] represents an array on JSON. {} represents an Object.

So in order to fetch the first element from you **json string**, you have to parse the string as a JSON element ;

```
var arr = JSON.parse('["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"]');
```

OR when you HAVE a **json array** already;

```
var arr = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"];
```

Then, go on and fetch the first value from your array which has index 0 as in all programming languages.

```
var url = arr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a normal array not a JSON, but if you want you can treat it as JSON:

```
    var image = JSON.parse('["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"]')[0];
console.log(image); //https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the difference between an array, and a JSON object.

I have given some examples of the differences and how to access them.

```js
// This is an array containing 1 value.
myobj = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"];
// it can be accessed by either the array name (since it only hase one value) or the array name and index of the  value in cases where the array actually has more than one value.
var example1 = [myobj];
document.write("This is my single value array:<br>" + example1 + "<br><br>");

// This is probably best practice regardless of the number of items in the array.
var example2 = myobj[0];
document.write("Now im specificing the index, incase there are more that one urls in the array:<br>" + example1 + "<br><br>");

// This is a JSON object
myJsonObj = {"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"}

// You access the value of the URL like this:
var example3 = myJsonObj.url;
document.write("Here is the value from a JSON object:<br>" + example3 );
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Just use parse function:

```
var text = '["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Cassini_Helene_N00086698_CL.jpg"]';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/esouc488/1/

Comment: This solution does not extract the string value from the array as asked by the OP.

Comment: Which array? There is no array mentioned in the question.

Comment: The square brackets (`[]`) delimit an array.